# In php my foreach loop with arrays seems to be written wrong but I'm not sure?

Tags: php, arrays, web, foreach, screen-scraping

Using php, I'm trying to get prices for all the things listed on a webpage.  Can someone please help me write this correctly?  I'm pretty sure I'm writing the foreach line wrong because of something having to do with $listing?  Also I'm not sure if the way the long parts is written is correct, that put the names and prices into $name and $price variables?

```
<?php
$all = file_get_contents('http://shop.hobbylobby.com/search/?keyword=cricut%20cartridge&match=AND&F_Sort=2&F_ALL=Y');
echo $all;
$name = array();
$price = array();
foreach($all as $listing) {
$name[] = $listing.GetElementsByClassName("listingWrpr").GetElementsByTagName("h3").innerhtml;
$price[] = $listing.GetElementsByClassName("listingWrpr").GetElementsByClassName("item price").innerhtml;
}
print_r($name);
print_r($price);
?>
```

Comment: The problem is not the foreach, but rather the attempt to use Javascript in PHP - the two can talk to each other, but don't mix.   You should use PHP DOM methods to extract the information

Comment: How can I do that without 6 weeks and an IQ of 200?

Comment: you can also use simple_html_Dom_Parser or phpQuery

Answer (score 1):

You have to use any of the following alternatives.

1. [simple html dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)
2. [PHPquery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/)
3. [snoopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/)

These are the `PHP` scripts which will count the table rows as well as you can work it as a `jQuery` functions.

I am giving you a example for this with the help of simple html dom parser.

```
 include("../simplehtml/simple_html_dom.php");


$html = file_get_html("YOUR URL");
foreach ($html->find('.logo') as $e) {
        $obj = str_get_html($e);
        foreach ($obj->find('img') as $ea) {
            $logoImage =  $e->innertext;
        }
    }
```

hope this helps.